# Compiling Python 2.7.2 with google-perftools

Tags: python, compilation, google-perftools

I have a debian squeeze operating system (64 bits). I want to use python with google-perftools. To perform that I compiled myself python 2.72 with the option "-lctmalloc". But I get few errors.

1. I installed libuwind because google-perftool asks for this package while using 64 bits
2. I installed all the packages needed :

Steps:

```
> sudo apt-get -y install build-essential 
> sudo apt-get -y install zlib1g-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libssl-dev libncurses5-dev  
> sudo apt-get -y install libreadline6-dev autotools-dev autoconf automake libtool 
> sudo apt-get -y install libsvn-dev mercurial subversion git-core 
> sudo apt-get -y install libbz2-dev libgdbm-dev sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev 
> sudo apt-get -y install curl libcurl4-gnutls-dev 
> sudo apt-get -y install libevent-dev libev-dev librrd4 rrdtool 
> sudo apt-get -y install uuid-dev libdb4.8-dev memcached libmemcached-dev  
> sudo apt-get -y install libmysqlclient-dev libexpat1-dev 
> sudo apt-get -y install google-perftool 
> cd python 
> export CFLAGS='-ltcmalloc' 
> ./configure 
> make
```

and that is what i got :

```
gcc  -Xlinker -export-dynamic -o python \
            Modules/python.o \
            libpython2.7.a -ldl  -lutil   -lm  
libpython2.7.a(posixmodule.o): In function `posix_tmpnam':
/home/toto/python272/Python-2.7.2/./Modules/posixmodule.c:7370: warning: the use of `tmpnam_r' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
libpython2.7.a(posixmodule.o): In function `posix_tempnam':
/home/toto/python272/Python-2.7.2/./Modules/posixmodule.c:7317: warning: the use of `tempnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
libpython2.7.a(thread.o): In function `_pythread_pthread_set_stacksize':
/home/toto/python272/Python-2.7.2/Python/thread_pthread.h:491: undefined reference to `pthread_attr_setstacksize'
libpython2.7.a(thread.o): In function `PyThread_release_lock':
/home/toto/python272/Python-2.7.2/Python/thread_pthread.h:346: undefined reference to `sem_post'
libpython2.7.a(thread.o): In function `PyThread_acquire_lock':
/home/toto/python272/Python-2.7.2/Python/thread_pthread.h:323: undefined reference to `sem_trywait'
/home/toto/python272/Python-2.7.2/Python/thread_pthread.h:321: undefined reference to `sem_wait'
libpython2.7.a(thread.o): In function `PyThread_free_lock':
/home/toto/python272/Python-2.7.2/Python/thread_pthread.h:292: undefined reference to `sem_destroy'
libpython2.7.a(thread.o): In function `PyThread_allocate_lock':
/home/toto/python272/Python-2.7.2/Python/thread_pthread.h:268: undefined reference to `sem_init'
libpython2.7.a(thread.o): In function `PyThread_start_new_thread':
/home/toto/python272/Python-2.7.2/Python/thread_pthread.h:183: undefined reference to `pthread_attr_setstacksize'
/home/toto/python272/Python-2.7.2/Python/thread_pthread.h:193: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/home/toto/python272/Python-2.7.2/Python/thread_pthread.h:209: undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
libpython2.7.a(thread.o): In function `PyThread_acquire_lock':
/home/toto/python272/Python-2.7.2/Python/thread_pthread.h:321: undefined reference to `sem_wait'
libpython2.7.a(thread.o): In function `PyThread_release_lock':
/home/toto/python272/Python-2.7.2/Python/thread_pthread.h:346: undefined reference to `sem_post'
/home/toto/python272/Python-2.7.2/Python/thread_pthread.h:346: undefined reference to `sem_post'
/home/toto/python272/Python-2.7.2/Python/thread_pthread.h:346: undefined reference to `sem_post'
libpython2.7.a(thread.o): In function `PyThread_allocate_lock':
/home/toto/python272/Python-2.7.2/Python/thread_pthread.h:268: undefined reference to `sem_init'
/home/toto/python272/Python-2.7.2/Python/thread_pthread.h:268: undefined reference to `sem_init'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [python] Error 1
You have new mail in /var/mail/root
```

I really don't understand this error when I do exactly the same without CFLAGS='-ltcmalloc', I am able to compile.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I guess, you should be using export LDFLAGS='-ltcmalloc' and not just CFLAGS.

Comment: also you should be including :  -lpthread

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH :
I smply added 
LDFLAGS='-ltcmalloc -lpthread'
CFLAGS='-ltcmalloc -lpthread'

Comment: I added it as answer or else it will remain a open question with no answers.

Comment: The [docs](http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/cpuprofile.html) mention environment variable `LD_PRELOAD`.  That might be something to look into.

Answer (score 1):

Use LDFlags

> -ltcmalloc

and it requires posix thread support.

> -lpthread